# Transliterate cyrillic file name using Python

Tags: python

I have a lot of files, which are named using cyrillic letters. To solve the problem I made a transliterate function, which looks like so:

```
def transliterate(input):
    mapping = { \
        'А' : 'A', \
        'Б' : 'B', \
        'В' : 'V', \
    .....
    }
    for c in input:
        if c in mapping:
            input = input.replace(c, mapping[c])

    return input
```

Visually, this function works good. I write the resulting file names to Postgre database and this is what I see there:

[image]

As you can see, I no longer have any cyrillic letters. When, however, in my Python code I create a subprocess command using these files names, I get really strange errors:

[image]

You see, that even on the screen it looks like a normal file name `79-A.tif`, but the tool which consumes this file interprets this name in some strange manner (I marked it in red). If however I instead just type the name by hand, then it works. So, what is wrong with that and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to fix it, but I have a debugging suggestion.  It's possible that the file name at some location (within your program) still contains some non-printing character.  Loop through the offending file name (by char) and print the char and its ordinal value.  If you see a blank next to a weird value, there's your culprit.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it. BTW, I also tried this library - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transliterate . But still have the very same result. Probably the whole problem with Postgresql?

Comment: PostgreSQL is a possible problem point; it's often hard to track character handling through multiple tools, as many of them subscribed to the best available standard at the time -- but at different times.